# call different controllers when click on different button clicks in view.

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am working on mvc4. My view page in contains 3 buttons as ***LOOKUP***,***LOOKUP2***,***INSERT***.
my requirement is i want to fire different controllers when i click on these 3 buttons.That means when i click on ***LOOKUP*** button i want to call ***iamlookup1*** controller.And when i click on ***LOOKUP2*** i want to fire ***iamlookup2*** as well as if i click on "***INSERT***" i want to call ***iaminsert*** should fire.Please post any code for this

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    text inside form1.
    </div>
    </form>
    <form id="form2" runat="server">
    test inside form2
    </form>
    <form id="form3" runat="server">
    text inside form3
    </form>
    This is some text outside the forms.
</body>
</html>
```

each form you can call one controller,hope this is help

Comment: Any other solutions like @url.action("actionname","controller");